# Usage of symbols, less than and larger than

Tags: notation

This is probably a stupid question, but I have to ask anyway since it's been bothering me since my lecturer said it. He said that $20\leq x \leq 35$ cannot be written as $35\geq x\geq 20$ since "$35$ can't be larger than $20$". I have been taught that those two are the same and I find his argumentation strange.
Can $20\leq x \leq 35$ be written as $35\geq x\geq 20$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lecturer is wrong (assuming you have understood and reported his claim correctly). $a \le b$ is exactly equivalent to $b \ge a$, usually by definition. So "$20 \le x \le 35$" and "$35 \ge x \ge 20$" are equivalent.

Also, 35 **is** larger than 20, so I have no idea what that explanation is about.

Comment: I quoted exactly what he said. He talked about that some students use the latter expression and that it is "just wrong"..

Comment: @efk Well, I didn't say you didn't report him correctly. I only stated that I am assuming you did report him correctly. Obviously, we here on mathSE cannot actually verify whether you are reporting what someone actually said, or whether you are mistaken, or whether you are just trolling, so there is no point arguing about it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to argue, I just wanted to clarify that it was his own words (translated into English).

Comment: @efk No problem. Anyway, what he said is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can, the two chains are the same!

Answer (score 0):

20≤x≤35         ___|_______________|______|________|________________|________
                 -35              -20      0       20               35

-35 is less than or equal to x is less than or equal to -20.
-20 is greater than or equal to x is greater than or equal to -35

20 is less than or equal to x is less than or equal to 35.
35 is greater than or equal to x is greater than or equal to 20